# What is the difference between a Type and an Abstract Type?

Tags: data-structures, type-theory, abstract-data-types

In my data structures course we are given definitions for **Type** and **Abstract Type** but they confuse me.

> A type is a set of values and the operations you can do on them. The set of operations is called an interface.

Wait, what? Do this mean that Type = set of values + interface?

> An Abstract Type is a type only accessible through its interface.

I fail to see how this differ from the Type definition. You always need to use the interface in order to do anything with the set of values. Are there types that can be accessed without having a set of operations defined on them a.k.a an interface?

Comment: You're trying to make sense of two botched explanations.

Comment: Could you please give me good definitions?

Comment: I suggest finding a good textbook on type theory.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type for an imprecise overview.

Comment: I don't think I can give you two succinct definitions that will make things clear. The notions of "type" and "abstract type" are open-ended and our understanding of them changes with time. In a good textbook you will find precise definitions that will certainly help, but only after working with them for a while. Just reading two short definitions would not be illuminating. Also, do not put too much emphasis on what "definitions" your teacher provided. Take those as intuitive explanations, and follow closely what your teacher is *doing* with types and abstract types. Good luck!